# Add/remove image programmatically to product Magento2

Tags: magento2

I am facing problem to add/remove image to product programmatically.

Comment: This question can't possibly be answered with how little information is available. You haven't even *asked* a question, technically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use following code to add/remove image from product in Magento2.

```
// Instance of object manager
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
*Remove Images From Product*/
$productId = ; // Id of product
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$productRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$existingMediaGalleryEntries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry) {
    unset($existingMediaGalleryEntries[$key]);
}
$product->setMediaGalleryEntries($existingMediaGalleryEntries);
$productRepository->save($product);
/*Add Images To The Product*/
$imagePath = "sample.png"; // path of the image
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
$product->save();
```

Comment: Ok I will try to make changes as per above code.Thanks for your reply.

Comment: i am trying this solution my image removes work good and image add also works good but it is not set as base small and thumbnail

Comment: $attributeImage = array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail');
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
          $product->addImageToMediaGallery( $file , $attributeImage, true,false );
$product->save();

Please try this it may help you.

Comment: I have used the same code and its working fine when there are only one store views. But if we have multiple store views then it not able to remove the images.

Comment: how can get the image path ?

Comment: where i need to give the file path