# How to remove product's image programmatically at Magento2.1.3?

Tags: magento2

I need to update product's images programmaticaly. Delete all product's images and add new.
I have test the solution from [Add/remove image programmatically to product Magento2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259303/add-remove-image-programmatically-to-product-magento2)
But it doesn't work for me. It doesn't remove images. I test it on Magento 2.1.3.

I google for another solution but they are the same.

How to remove product's image programmatically at Magento2.1.3?

Thank you.

Comment: give us some more debug information, what is is $existingMediaGalleryEntries do the product save correctly?

Comment: Hmm. What debug info do you need?
Images to products were add programaticaly on Magento 2.1.1 using
`$_product->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()));
$_product->addImageToMediaGallery($imageShortPath . $imageFileName, array('image','thumbnail','small_image'), false, false);`

I notice that doesn't allow to remove this image via admin panel, unless I disable all images roles 'base', 'small', 'thumb' for all storeview.

Delete doesn't work only for old images.
I can delete new images, but new images doesn't have roles.

I think the main issue in images roles.

Comment: I found the issue description - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7647

But I don't find the solution. How to remove roles from image programmatically.

Comment: any update on the matter?